# Error: The Request Property(s) Email do not match with the fields of EmailSendDefinition retrieve

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

In the [official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/emailsenddefinition.htm), the `EmailSendDefinition` object has an `Email` property.

The same I see in the WSDL schema:

```xml
<complexType name="EmailSendDefinition">
  <complexContent>
    <extension base="tns:SendDefinition">
      <sequence>
         ...
         <element name="Email" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="tns:Email"/>
```

I am sending the following `POST` request:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://{{et_subdomain}}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{dne_etAccessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options>
        </Options>
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>EmailSendDefinition</ObjectType>
            <Properties>Email</Properties>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And I get:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <env:Header xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:...</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:...</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-...">
                <wsu:Created>2021-06-09T21:14:28Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2021-06-09T21:19:28Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </env:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>Error: The Request Property(s) Email do not match with the fields of EmailSendDefinition retrieve</OverallStatus>
            <RequestID>...</RequestID>
        </RetrieveResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

If instead of `Email` I use, for an example, `EmailSubject`, I get the data, but some fields are not retrievable as the `Email` field.

How can I distinguish retrievable and non-retrievable fields?
How can I retrieve the `Email` of a particular `EmailSendDefinition`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EmailSendDefinitions don't tend to get used that much these days, but you can view the retrievability/updatability of a SOAP object by using a Describe operation. The SOAPAction header needs to be "Describe". Here's a sample payload:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <fueloauth>{{_token}}</fueloauth>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <DefinitionRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <DescribeRequests>
            <ObjectDefinitionRequest>
               <ObjectType>EmailSendDefinition</ObjectType>
            </ObjectDefinitionRequest>
         </DescribeRequests>
      </DefinitionRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

You'll see that "Email.ID" is a property that is retrievable. So, you can use this in your retrieve of the EmailSendDefinition.

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
        <fueloauth>{{_token}}</fueloauth>
    </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>EmailSendDefinition</ObjectType>
            <Properties>Email.ID</Properties>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: The answer is right, I just wanted to comment because I disagree that EmailSendDefinitions don't tend to get used that much these days. Honestly, almost every single client I have uses these on a near daily basis. This is because for bulk sends using the Automation Studio Email Send (User-Initiated Send aka Email Send Definition) is best practice for scheduling bulk sends. By doing this, you remove the 'caching' of the email creative on schedule so you can update the email without requiring canceling and rescheduling of your sends.

Comment: @Gortonington My drift was, "do you want to retrieve the 'Send' object?". Yes. It's an overstretch. "almost every single client I have uses these on a near daily basis"... my ones, not so much. I'm not against, but my clients are more into consistency and can't handle too many ways of doing the same thing, bless them. They get the "techies" to sort out Automation Studio and do that "SQL stuff". Journey Builder's for them. I don't see an awful lot of ESDs being created, unless I do it for them.

Comment: Usage is contextual I will agree, I just wanted to point out they are still in use in many places.